# Rails detecting Facebook share vs normal page view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, heroku

I'm trying to detect a crawl when a user shares a page via the Facebook share button; However, when looking at the live logs, nothing appears to be hitting my controller when I click on the button.

The idea was to detect the `user-agent` and render different content to be shared vs when a user actually visits the site.

In my controller I have the following:

```
def show
  Rails::logger.debug "********************************"
  Rails::logger.debug "#{self.class.name} - params: #{params.inspect}"
  Rails::logger.debug "#{self.class.name} - request.headers['HTTP_USER_AGENT']: #{request.headers['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].inspect}"
  Rails::logger.debug "********************************"

  render "pages/fb_test", layout: false
end
```

**share button**

```
.fb-share-button{:"data-href" => "http://myapp.herokuapp.com/pages/1", :"data-layout" => "button", :"data-size" => "small", :"data-mobile-iframe" => false}
  %a.fb-xfbml-parse-ignore{target: "_blank", href: "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://myapp.herokuapp.com/pages/1"}
    Share
```

I would assume that when I click on the share button, Facebook would hit the URL provided, crawl the page and return the relevant content. However, when using `heroku logs --tail` I'm not seeing any activity at all when I click on the share button, and yet the content is still rendered properly in the Facebook share popup.

Do I need to detect this at the `Rack` level or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook caches your website. You'll need to go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/, enter the URL of your website and click on "Scrape again" to refresh Facebook's cache.